# Using a struct to determine a point in a plane - C

Tags: c, struct

**ISSUE:**
Trying to figure out a point in a place `x` and `y`, then represent the point in a place as a structure having two fields.

So depending on the function that accepts the structure, it will return either 1, 2, 3, or 4. (Those are the 4 quadrants)

If x and y are positive, quadrant 1,
if x is negative and y is positive, 2
If x is negative and y is negative, quadrant 3,
and if x is positive and y is negative, quadrant 4.

Most of my issue is not completely understanding the question, do I take in 2 values for x and y using the struct and return the number?

Also, how do I interact with my struct? 
Hope I provided enough info, that's pretty much all I have.

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct coord
{
    int x;
    int y;

}POINT;


int main(){
int the_point;

scanf("%d", &the_point);
POINT * coord = malloc(50 * sizeof(POINT));

if (the_point)



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear, what do you want us to answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, how do you read in the point. It looks like you scanf into `the_point`. This variable is only an int, meaning unless you plan to parse it or otherwise manipulate it, you have to decide if this is the x-value or y-value in the problem. It would be better to be explicit for the user to input the coords of the point. Such as:

```
printf("Enter the x-coord of the input: ");
scanf("%d", &the_point);
///
///assign the_point to the x-coord
///

// do the same thing for y-coord
```

You will use the arrow-operators to access the fields within a struct such as:

```
myStruct->field1 = some_var
```

You can use this same syntax to run your conditional checks on the individual fields.

Comment: okay, I think I understand, is it the same way when I'm trying to call by tag and not type?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by tag and not type. If you're referring to variable type, you cannot refer to it by tag. A common practice would be to accept the input as a string such as (3,2) and parse out the comma and assign to your struct (after validating input).

Comment: Don't forget about malloc() and free() or you'll get some memory usage issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand the question I highly recommend clarifying the question with your professor/boss/client.  Email, talk, call whoever you need.  Check with coworkers and other students.  Trying to answer a question you don't understand is not good.

Structs are just "containers" that can hold various types of data in c.  Besides holding the data they don't really do much else.

Here are some examples of interacting with a struct and passing it to a function
https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-passing-struct-to-function/

Don't do the last option (use a global struct) unless you have a specific reason why you know your struct should be global.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for:

```
if (the_point[i].x < 0) {
    if (the_point[i].y < 0) {
        // quadrant 3
    }
    else {
        // quadrant 2
    }
}
else {
    if (the_point[i].y < 0) {
        // quadrant 4
    }
    else {
        // quadrant 1
    }
}
```

And the input line would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    scanf("%d %d", &the_point[i].x, &the_point[i].y);
}
```

Also, the_point had to be declared as:

```
POINT the_point[50];
```

Comment: If you swap `x` and `y` the quadrants will be correct.

Comment: Yep! First I've numbered the quadrants in clockwise order (as usual) but the question sorts in counterclockwise order.

Comment: Counter-clockwise is usual as used in the question. Please see [Quadrant (plane geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)).

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think it's OK now. And you're right; the correct order would be in the counterclockwise.